# Get Romaji from google translation website

Tags: c#, winforms, translation

i am trying to use the translation code bellow to get the romaji words for a specific set of japanese characters, but i can't get the romaji character to even show up the url i download, it's not even in the Google Translate page source code, this is my code:

```
string languagePair = "jp|en";
string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", "本", languagePair);
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
Clipboard.SetText(result);
```

the character in my code is just an example, it's supposed to say *Hon*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For japanese language you must use `ja` ISO 639-1 Code as described [here](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/03/useful-google-translate-addresses.html):

> Notes:
>  
>   1. the language pairs are listed in this FAQ, while the language codes are included in [this long list](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php).

So, you must change your code to this:

```
string languagePair = "ja|en";
string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", "本", languagePair);
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
Clipboard.SetText(result);
```

Result page:
[image: Result page]